# How to get rid of "New version of plugin" message in Wordpress?

Tags: version, wordpress

I am writing my first Wordpress custom plugin, and I've entered some basic info into the comments section.

However in my admin panel I keep seeing the message:

"There is a new version of {nameofplugin}"

I've made sure that the plugin name does not exist, and even typed in random characters but regardless the message keeps appearing.

But there isn't a new version of said plugin at all as I've just started to write it and have no intention of making it public as it is custom for this client's requirements.

How do I get rid of this message?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable the update notification you could use one of the following plugins

<del>http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/plugin-update-blocker/</del>
<del>http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/disable-wordpress-plugin-updates/</del>

**Updated plugins:**

https://wordpress.org/plugins/hide-plugin-updates-notifications/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/block-specific-plugin-updates/

Comment: That'll do. I'm only disabling the one plugin. Answer accepted. Thanks.